# How to solve the ODE $2x\frac{dy}{dx}=C(1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2)^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling with this ODE I obtained when solving the Euler-Lagrange equation.
Can any one help me with solving the ODE

$$2x\frac{dy}{dx}=C(1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2)^2$$

Thanks so much!

It comes from **the Euler-Lagrange equation of the following problem.**
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Mattos I tried separation of variables. But the $(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$ on the right hand side. I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: @Mattos I tried change of variable, but that seems not work. Can you give me some suggestions？Ｔｈａｎｋｓ！

Comment: Where did this ode come from?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Hi, Mhenni. I edited the problem. It comes from the E-L equation of a problem.

Comment: Try converting it to Volterra Integral Equation

Comment: You may need to solve a polynomial equation from order of 4 to obtain $y'$ based on x then integrate it. solving 4th order polynomial needs Ferrari's Method.

Comment: i don't know how useful this is, but you can solve you equation for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a function of $x.$

Comment: You should use approximation methods.

Comment: Just letting you know this equation can be represented in another form $\frac{1}{1+y'^2}=\frac{-2}{c} (y' x -y) + C_0$. You probably can find the $C_0$. If you may think it makes the equation simpler but i dont think so!